Inverter interharmonic in simulation? Is this typical? Unstable at ~50ms mark?
I am trying to learn about inverter design, and I am simulating a basic sinusoidal PWM controlled, 3ph inverter on PSIM, the load has a PF~0.9 and the switches are ideal in the inverter. I had a few questions about these waveforms I am getting:
In the FFT why am I spiking at ~80 Hz when my carrier freq is 900Hz and modulating frequency is 60 Hz? This is called an interharmonic correct? It seems to only be in the current switching waveform and the load waveforms, not the voltage switching waveforms? There also seems to be a spike ~104 hz, but I think that is filtered out effectively in the output.
What is going on before the load waveforms reach steady state? Is that big dip ~50ms from the 80Hz interharmonic? I assume it is as 1/80~ 12.5ms and 50/12.5 is an integer, so that would land right on one of the peaks or valleys of that harmonic.
Any other pointers of what to look out for when modeling these things would be appreciated! I am going to try overmodulating and using third harmonic injection after I sort out what is going on with this basic sim and eventually move on to SVM. Really trying to nail out some basics first.
If any other waveforms would be useful, let me know, I can get them posted up here pretty fast!
R=10 Ohms, L=.001 H, C=.00396 F -> +.9 PF




You have no feedback in this inverter sim. So is it just a high-Q LC resonance? When you get a sudden load step (such as at the start of your simulation), you excite this resonance.

Ya there is no feedback I am working through a textbook and this is supposed to just demonstrate sinusoidal PWM and where its harmonics are typically placed.  I did eventually only use the steady state portion of the waveforms to do the FFT and it looked much more like the textbook waveforms.
Now that you mention Q-factors I guess this looks underdamped because it oscillates a bit then calms down to steady state.
